# How to remove text/characters from an Excel cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking for a way to remove any text from a cell and leave just numbers. So far I have found a few examples, but they either target predefined text or specialized characters.

```
SUBSTITUTE(A1, ".", "")
SUBSTITUTE(text, old_text, new_text, [nth_appearance])
```

Example, my cell can contain mixed text and numbers in any position, so how do I just leave the numbers and remove any characters...

```
lorem1001ipsum
ipsum01lorem
0101lorem
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select your cells and run this small macro:

```
Sub qwerty()
    For Each r In Selection
        vout = ""
        v = r.Text
        n = Len(v)
        For i = 1 To n
            ch = Mid(v, i, 1)
            If ch Like "[0-9]" Then
                vout = vout & ch
            End If
        Next i
        r.Value = vout
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: This keeps numbers and removes everything else, which is cool. How do I keep all numbers and periods (.), but remove everything else?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep all numbers and period (for example, decimal numbers), add elseif to check for period. Code:

```
Sub qwerty() 
    For Each r In Selection
        vout = ""
        v = r.Text
        n = Len(v)
        For i = 1 To n
            ch = Mid(v, i, 1)
            If ch Like "[0-9]" Then
                vout = vout & ch
            ElseIf ch Like "." Then
                vout = vout & ch
            End If
        Next i
        r.Value = vout
    Next r
End Sub
```